# My onsavedInstanceState () did not work

Tags: android

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
if( savedInstanceState != null ) {
         Toast.makeText(this, "!=nulll" + savedInstanceState .getString("MyString"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      } else Toast.makeText(this, "=nulll", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

...i got some code here with a variable : String set ....

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);    
      savedInstanceState.putString("MyString", set);
  }
```

it tried, it always display : "=nulll".

Comment: How are you testing this?

Comment: I set the variabe. when i press the Back button to destroy my app , and turn on it again...

Comment: `onSavedInstanceState` won't be called on back press.  Back button is meant to destroy the app.  It is called when screen is rotated, if you press the home button or when the os kills the app if it is running out of memory.

Comment: oh . it worked. Thanks Naveed. but how can i set the same way when i touch the Back button ?

Comment: If you really need to save the state when back button is pressed, you can do it in `onPause` or `onBackPressed` use `sharedPreferences`, a `File` or a `database`.  I can add an answer if you want me to elaborate.

Comment: can you tell me more or where i can find my solution ? i want to save my variable : String set. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save a simple key-value pair then you can use sharedPreferences.  Look through the [Saving Data guide](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/index.html) for more details and how to save complex data.

Following is a shared preference example (borrowed from [saving key value set](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html))

```
//Restore it in onResmue()
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    SharedPreferences pref = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String myString = pref.contains("MyString") ? pref.getString("MyString", null) : null;
    if( myString != null ) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "!=nulll" + myString, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "=nulll", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); }
}

//Save it in onPause()
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
    editor.putString("MyString", set);
    editor.commit();

}
```

Be careful when using File or Sqlite, you will need to read the data back on a separate thread.  Again, go through [Saving Data guide](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/index.html) for more info.

Comment: i can't do that , because i have another activity to change the value of variable : set. if i put those code, i couldn't change the value of set. i think, i should try with sqlite .

Comment: my app have another problem : when my app is running, i change value of set :     set="2"     by     SettingActivity     , i press the Home button, and start it again . it work with     set="1"     ( that the default value i wrote in     mainActivity    ) in     layout X     (that the layout i wrote for     mainActivity    ), and when i press the Back button : it work with     set="2"     with     layout X    . ???

Comment: If I understand your question correctly; `sharedPreferences` are shared across the app so if you change the value of that variable and save it in shared preference in one activity, it will be reflected in another activity.